# Pseudo-terminals control each other, how to get the return display

Tags: centos, devices, pty

The problem is: my pseudo-terminal is /dev/pts/0, the target pseudo-terminal is /dev/pts/4, and I'm trying to get the target pseudo-terminal to print text using the echo text > /dev/pts/4 command.

So the first question is: after I use echo text > /dev/pts/4 command, the target host does display the text back, but one disadvantage is that the target will display another line after displaying the text back, and you have to manually press ctrl + c to end it, how can I avoid the above situation?

Secondly, I think after using man pty > /dev/pts/4, the target pseudo-terminal does open a pty manual, but the downside is that my pseudo-terminal also produces a blank line after the text is displayed, and no matter how much I try to end it with ctrl + c, it doesn't work, and the only way to fix it is to just shut down my pseudo-terminal. So I tried running man pty > /dev/pts/4 & in the background again, and my pseudo-terminal didn't show the blank line, but the target pseudo-terminal didn't show the man manual.

So the second problem is: how to make the target pseudo-terminal display the man manual normally, but my pseudo-terminal doesn't display the blank line carriage return.

The last problem is that I want to intercept all displays of the target pseudo-terminal.

There are a lot of questions and descriptions, thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

It may be expecting additional input. Sending the line feed might help signal to the target shell that the command is complete:

```
echo -n text > /dev/pts/4
```

Or use `-e` to add the newline, same difference:

```
echo -e "text\n" > /dev/pts/4
```

You can use the `-s` option with `man`, like this:

```
man -s pty > /dev/pts/4
```

This **should** prevent the target pseudo-terminal from showing the new line after the manual page loads. The "proper" way to redirect a `man` page is with the `script` command, which creates a new shell session for interaction:

```
script -q -c 'man pty' /dev/pts/4
```

Make sure the environment variables (like **TERM** and **PAGER**) are correctly set for the target terminal.

To intercept all output that goes to a specific pseudo-terminal, you can use `tee`. However, intercepting all output of another terminal can be difficult when processes are directly writing to `/dev/pts/4`.

```
{ echo "text" ; other_command ; } | tee /dev/pts/4
```

This will send the output of `echo "text"` and `other_command` to the current terminal and `/dev/pts/4`.

Where you want to capture **anything** a process sends to `/dev/pts/4`, you would need to involve system call tracing or terminal multiplexers like `screen` or `tmux` that allow session sharing and logging.

Oh, and `tee` could also help with the blank line: `echo text | tee /dev/pts/4`.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in my reply, I tried all the commands you provided and the results are.
The first command:echo -n text > /dev/pts/4 will wait for additional input at the end of the line, the second command:echo -e "text\n" > /dev/pts/4 will not help to signal to the target shell that the command has been completed, but instead it will be on a blank line, still waiting for additional input, the third command:man -s pty > /dev/pts/4 I don't know why my terminal displays an error here, it comes back and tells me "What manual page do you want?".

Comment: The fourth command, script -q -c 'man pty' /dev/pts/4 did open the man manual on the target after I sent it, but my pseudo-terminal also opened the man manual, and when I typed q into the pseudo-terminal, the target pseudo-terminal exited and displayed a line of echo from the beginning of the record. The fifth command { echo "text" ;} | tee /dev/pts/4 did get displayed, but the target pseudo-terminal got a blank line and waited for input.

Comment: As far as the terminal not working with ctrl+c, I can't reproduce. Ctrl+C, or simply pressing enter, will free the terminals. `screen` will send the man page but all control of it's viewing is on the other tty(pty). There's not many actual tty's left. TTY stands for teletype. Dot matrix printers with ink ribbons (Where CRLF came from). Run commands `w`, `tty`, `ps ax|grep $$` to get a visual. You're really after is file descriptors. I'll redo this post and detail it.  For now: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/send-command-to-another-terminal-and-press-enter-4175659895/